# Regex for first number after a number and period

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an ordered list with names and addresses that is structured like:

```
1. Last, First  123 Main St  buncha 
    buncha buncha

2. Lasta, Firsta 234 Lane St etc etc
```

So I need a regex that finds the number that immediately follows the number with a period. So in this case an array containing `[123, 234]`.  I have a couple of patterns I've tried. The one that I think is the closest is

```
/(?![0-9]+\.)[0-9]+/gim;
```

unfortunately this just returns every number, but i think its in the right area. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a positive lookbehind to explicitly match the number, period, and the text between that and the number in the address.

```js
const string = `1. Last, First  123 Main St  buncha 
    buncha buncha

2. Lasta, Firsta 234 Lane St etc etc`;

let regex = /(?<=^\d+\.\D*)\d+/gm;

console.log(string.match(regex));
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```js
const source = 
`1. Last, First  123 Main St  buncha 
    buncha buncha

2. Lasta, Firsta 234 Lane St etc etc`;

const result = source.match(/(?<=(\d+\..+))\d+/gm);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a capturing group

```
^\d+\.\D*(\d+)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\d+\.` Match 1+ digits and `.`
- `\D*` Match 0+ any char except a digit
- `(\d+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2AblBO/1)

```js
const regex = /^\d+\.\D*(\d+)/gm;
const str = `1. Last, First  123 Main St  buncha
    buncha buncha

2. Lasta, Firsta 234 Lane St etc etc`;

let res = Array.from(str.matchAll(regex), m => m[1]);
console.log(res);
```